# Adding nonzero items from a dictionary to another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a set of reactions (keys) with values (0.0 or 100) stored in mydict.
Now I want to place non zero values in a new dictionary (nonzerodict).

```
def nonzero(cmod):
    mydict = cmod.getReactionValues()
    nonzerodict = {}
    for key in mydict:
        if mydict.values() != float(0):
            nonzerodict[nz] = mydict.values
        print nz
```

Unfortunately this is not working.
My questions:

- Am I iterating over a dictionary correctly?
- Am I adding items to the new dictionary correctly?

Comment: your if condition is wrong. It checks a list with float.

Comment: `if mydict[key] != float(0):`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to replace these ``zeros`` with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing if the *list of values* is not equal to `float(0)`. Test *each value* instead, using the key to retrieve it:

```
if mydict[key] != 0:
    nonzerodict[key] = mydict[key]
```

You are iterating over the keys correctly, but you could also iterate over the key-value pairs:

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    if value != 0:
        nonzerodict[key] = value
```

Note that with floating point values, chances are you'll have *very small* values, close to zero, that you may want to filter out too. If so, test if the value is *close* to zero instead:

```
if abs(value) > 1e-9:
```

You can do the whole thing in a single dictionary expression:

```
def nonzero(cmod):
    return {k: v for k, v in cmod.getReactionValues().iteritems() if abs(v) > 1e-9}
```

Comment: and ``nonzerodict[nz] = mydict.values`` will probably not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Replace if condition in you code with:

```
if mydict[key]:
    nonzerodict[key] = mydict[key]
```

Your solution can be further simplified as:

```
def nonzero(cmod):
    mydict = cmod.getReactionValues()
    nonzerodict = {key: value for key, value in mydict.iteritems() if value}
```

Comment: please provide some more context instead of just a codeblock. Also on Python3 there is no ``.iteritems()``.

Comment: @MSeifert: we know the OP is using Python 2; they used `print` as a statement.

Comment: shame on me, I haven't realized that. But I'm always confused when a proposed solution doesn't work for me ... why chose the approach in the answer instead of the equivalent ``{key: mydict[key] for key in mydict if mydict[key]}`` which works for both python2 and 3?

Comment: @MSeifert: because `dict.iteritems()` is faster for that case; each `obj[..]` expression takes extra work.

Comment: @MSeifert: polyglot code usually uses a wrapper function to switch between using `dict.iteritems()` and `dict.items()`.

Comment: @MSeifert : Performance wise `{key: value for key, value in mydict.iteritems() if value}` is faster than `{key: mydict[key] for key in mydict if mydict[key]}`. While doing `mydict[key]` you make search in dictionary each time for the corresponding value of the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple and you can it by below way -

```
>>> d = {'a':4,'b':2, 'c':0}
>>> dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if v!=0)
{'a': 4, 'b': 2}
>>>
```